# "InstallProhibited" received from device

Tags: iphone, provisioning, ios4

I recently updated my iPhone to iOS 4.0.1 and I cannot use the device for development any more. I have the following error when Xcode installs the app on the device:

"InstallProhibited" received from device.

The provisioning profiles are correctly installed and I could use the device for testing before the iOS update.

Did anyone encountered this error? I googled a bit but couldn't find anything related.

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the **Settings->General->Restrictions** setting on your device.

Comment: @Adri1 You are welcome. It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: In Restrictions, **Installing Apps** should be enabled to fix this issue.